# Select specific for-each template in XSLT file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
Hello everyone,

Suppose we have an xslt file

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
        <xsl:function name="grp:MapToCD538A_var107">
            <xsl:param name="var106_cur" as="node()"/>
            <xsl:param name="var106_cur" as="node()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$var106_cur/containerIdentificationNumber">
            <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:function>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <CD123>
                <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="(./ns0:CD538C)[fn:not(fn:exists(*:ExportOperation[fn:namespace-uri() eq '']/*:requestRejectionReasonCode[fn:namespace-uri() eq '']))]">
                    <SynIde xmlns="">UN1OC</SynIde>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </CD123>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and i want to select only the for-each inside `<CD123>` node. Not the others for-each

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:for-each">
 <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <!-- PULL PARENT AND SIBLING NODES -->
    <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>       
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With the xslt code above i apply these lines to every for-each. How do i apply these lines only to the desired for-each?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as easy as `match="CD123/xsl:for-each"`.

Comment: Thank you! can i also implement this with something like <xsl:template match="xsl:for-each select="(./ns0:CD538C)"> ?

Comment: @rammale91, well, you asked about that parent element, of course you can match based on e.g. `match="xsl:for-each[starts-with(@select, '(./ns0:CD538C)')]"` but that is a completely different match.